# View models in Servicestack

Tags: servicestack

The term *Viewmodel* is mentioned in the Servicestack documentation and here and there in questions/answers at Stackoverflow.

Is this referring to viewmodels á la dotNET MVC all the time ?
Is this always used in conjunction with MVC/MVCcore ?

I'm asking myself if I missed reading up on this type of functionality in Servicestack. If so a pointer to where to start reading is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ViewModel is just the DTO that gets passed to the HTML view which is rendered when a HTML/Web Request is made to your Service. The Response DTO your Service returns is what gets passed to the view page to render the HTML Response, in this case the Response DTO is also the View Model (i.e. the Model used by the View).

The 2 popular technologies for rendering HTML views for your Services is:

1. [ServiceStack Templates](http://templates.servicestack.net/docs/view-engine#view-pages)
2. [ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/#smart-views)

Unlike MVC your same ServiceStack Services are used for both enabling Web Services and rendering Web Pages.

Comment: Talk about fast. Thanks @mythz.
Textual communication is hard. Documentation is harder. Searching is easy,   as long as you have the right vocabulary.